# Is it possible to hide fields on node edit form or split node edit form in two screens?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a content type cFoo. This content type has e.g 10 fields.

I want:

1. user has page node/cfooxx/edit/screen1 and sees only fields 1,2,3,4,5
2. user has page node/cfooxx/edit/screen2 and sees only fields 6,7,8
3. user has no access to fields 9,10

I did a lot of reseach on this but it is not clear for me.

- how to get the splitting of the standaard node/xx/edit url to edit/screen1 and edit/screen2?
- On the front I use display suite so I can manage a display. Is there a module which can do this with edit forms as well?
- If I use css, still fields of screen1 are processed in background of screen2 and the other way around. I do not want this because of possible errors in form validation. But suppose i need to do this... then the /node/cFooxx/edit url containts fields 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8. So how to decide which css to apply when entering /node/cFooxx/edit?
- If I use hook_form_alter how to identify screen1 and screen2?
- Point 3 I can solve with field permissions module

Comment: you can use form alter based on the argument, something like arg(3) == 'screen1', have you tried that ? i think in your case argument array arg() will help you

Answer (score 1):

You could use different modes on the two routes. Go to `/admin/structure/types/manage/fooxx/form-display` and there you can configure which fields you want see on which mode.

You can add new modes here: `/admin/structure/display-modes`

> **Note**: While Drupal 8 core already comes with "form modes", in Drupal 7 you need to install the
>   [flexiform](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexiform) module.
>
> [image]

Comment: for my understanding these modus can only be used for displaying (viewing) not for node form editing. Is that correct?

Comment: No, for example you can have a 'default' form for nodes and a 'settings' form.

Comment: @Justme updated this answer, since you originally didn't mention your Drupal version, Maouna assumed you were on D8.

Comment: Within D7 I installed Display Suite but still I do not understand how to split the EDIT screens. I do understand how to split the form DISPLAY screens. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

@Sanjay's solution is the only way I can think of. I had done the similar thing before for a similar situation as question stated.

I would separate the logic into 2 different functions.

```php
function mymodule_form_cfooxx_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

  switch (arg(3) {
    case "screen1":
      _mymodule_form_screen_1($form, $form_state);
      break;
    case "screen2":
      _mymodule_form_screen_2($form, $form_state);
  }

}

function _mymodule_form_screen_1(&$form, &$form_state) {
  ...
}

function _mymodule_form_screen_2(&$form, &$form_state) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Suppose I do this. How to get the fields display in scenario 2. So how to display only field 5 6 7?